# C# exception handling finally block before catch block

Tags: c#, exception

I am quite confused with how exceptions are getting thrown in C#. If an exception occurs, in the try block,
1.it gets thrown to the catch block,
2. If and only if the catch block catches it the finally block will be executed.
3. The finally block gets executed last, provided the catch statement caught it.

However, when I try to run the program below, the output is A,B not BA.Is there something wrong with my understanding? Thank you.

```
class Program
 {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         try
         {
             int a = 2;
             int b = 10 / a;
             try
             {
                 if (a == 1)
                     a = a / a - a;
                 if (a == 2)
                 {
                     int[] c = { 1 };
                     c[8] = 9;
                 }
             }
             finally
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("A");
             }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

The exception occurs in a==2, and I know the outer catch will catch this exception. However, the finally is being executed first? Any reason as to why this is showing?

### edited

From C# docs we know Finally block gets executed whether or not an exception has occured.

However, my finally block never gets executed and in return I am getting a run time error

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int a = 2;
            int b = 10 / a;
            try
            {
                if (a == 1)
                    a = a / a - a;
                if (a == 2)
                {
                    int[] c = { 1 };
                    c[8] = 9;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A");
            }
        }

        finally{
            Console.WriteLine("finally");
        }
        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally will be always executed independently you handle exception or not. So you will see `A` in console always and `B` if exception is of type IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: [Specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/exceptions.md#how-exceptions-are-handled): Once a matching `catch` clause is found, the system prepares to transfer control to the first statement of the `catch` clause. Before execution of the `catch` clause begins, the system first executes, in order, any `finally` clauses that were associated with `try` statements more nested that than the one that caught the exception.

Comment: Your edit relates to the second half of my answer, where no exception handler at all can be located for the exception.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did not understand it. Sorry but thank you for your answer

Comment: It seems someone is downvoting every answer. It would be helpful to leave a comment to explain the reason

Comment: `However, my finally block never gets executed and in return I am getting a run time error` That is not true. They are executed AND you get unhandled exception error on runtime. See here: [Test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GYNB76). You can see A and finally printed out and then an exception.

Comment: It seems you confuse a `finally` with a `catch`. The former doesn't handle the exception, it just ensures that this code gets executed after the try, no matter if there was an exception. The `catch` will handle the exception. So with `finally` you will still see the exception at runtime but the code in it was executed before. This code could be disposing unmanaged resources for example, so something that should happen always, even in case of an error.

Comment: @Reniuz - that's not *required* behaviour. I've added a link/quote from the standard that supports that a lack of any `catch` handlers at all can lead to an abort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code, the reason that the `finally` (A) runs before the `catch` (B) is because when the exception is thrown, you exit the inner block (causing the `finally` to run) before the outer block's `catch` comes into play.  Consider this code:

```
private void TestTryCatchFinally()
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start Outer Try");
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Start Inner Try");
            throw new Exception("Exception from inner try");
            Debug.WriteLine("End of Inner Try - never reaced");
        }
        //remove this catch block for second test
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("In inner catch");
        }
        //end of code to remove
        finally
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("In Inner Finally");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("In outer catch");
    }
    finally
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("In outer finally");
    }
}
```

If I run this code, I get this output:

```
Start Outer Try
Start Inner Try
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in MyTestApp.exe
In inner catch
In Inner Finally
In outer finally
```

Which is what you expect.  But, if I remove the inner catch block (as noted in the code), I get this output:

```
Start Outer Try
Start Inner Try
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in MyTestApp.exe
In Inner Finally
In outer catch
In outer finally
```

In this case, as soon as execution exits the inner try block, the finally code executes.  Then the outer catch block has it's turn.

Answer (score 5):

`finally` executes when control leaves the `try` block to which it is attached *for any reason*; not just if there was a `catch` block at the same level - that would be a `fault` handler (in CLR terms) which I think we still cannot do in C#.

So it enters the `finally` that prints `A` because control is leaving that `try` block. It's leaving it because of an exception that's being caught in an outer `catch` block. That doesn't change any timings/orderings however.

---

Note that there are some oddities that are possible if the exception is entirely uncaught anywhere in your code. Exception handling happens in two phases. In the first phase, it's trying to locate an appropriate `catch` clause for the exception, and that can include executing guard clauses ([`when`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when), C#6 and later). During the second phase, it unwinds the stack and executes any `finally` clauses as the nesting requires, before reaching the correct level at which the `catch` clause that will handle the exception is defined<sup>1</sup>.

I believe that in some environments, if the first phase fails to locate an appropriate exception handler (`catch` clause) *at all*, the entire managed environment may be torn down. In such circumstances, the `finally` clauses aren't executed.

All that is *required* by a standards conforming CLR is described in the MS Partition I.pdf document, found on [ECMA C# and Common Language Infrastructure Standards](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/ecma-c-common-language-infrastructure-standards/). Section 12.4.2.5 states:

> When an exception occurs, the CLI
>   searches the array for the first protected block that
>
> - Protects a region including the current instruction pointer *and*
> - Is a catch handler block *and*
> - Whose filter wishes to handle the exception
>
> If a match is not found in the current method, the calling method is searched, and so on. **If no match is found
>   the CLI will dump a stack trace and abort the program.**

(My **emphasis**)

---

<sup>1</sup>Illustrated using a variant of [Flydog57's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012339/15498), also C# 7 local functions:

```
using System;

namespace PlayAreaCSCon
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestTryCatchFinally();
            Console.WriteLine("Complete");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TestTryCatchFinally()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start Outer Try");
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Start Inner Try");
                    throw new Exception("Exception from inner try");
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("In Inner Finally");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (GuardHelper(ex))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In outer catch");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In outer finally");
            }

            bool GuardHelper(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In outer guard");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Start Outer Try
Start Inner Try
In outer guard
In Inner Finally
In outer catch
In outer finally
Complete
```

Illustrating the two-pass nature of the exception handling (that `In outer guard` is printed *before* `In Inner Finally`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single try-catch-finally block, it's true that catch precedes finally. But here, the try-finally and try-catch blocks are being run in order of innermost to outermost. Therefore the finally runs first.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this (depents on what you are actually trying to do)

```
class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     try
     {
         int a = 2;
         int b = 10 / a;

        if (a == 1)
            a = a / a - a;
        if (a == 2)
        {
            int[] c = { 1 };
            c[8] = 9;
        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
         //Do something when something in try block throws error
         Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
    finally
    {
        //This code will ALWAYS execute
        //Even when there is no error, A will be written to console
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Comment: I am trying to answer an mcq question

Comment: @Svenmarim No, you don't.

Comment: That is not true! You can use try-catch-finally, try-catch, try-finally variations.

Answer (score -1):

I may be missing something. Don't you want the following?

```
try
{          
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{  
}
```

By using a `finally{}` block, you can ensure that some statements will always run

Comment: I am actually trying to understand an mcq question, that is why the format is messed up in the first place. However "By using a finally{} block, you can ensure that some statements will always run" doesnt work. Kindly refer to my edit section. Thank you